# Trying to upload to Parse my votes for each individual image using swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am making an app that has a tableview of images and can be upvoted or downvoted by swiping right or left. Im trying to have the votes be logged in to parse on the backend meanwhile i want the votes to appear in each cell. i have added a voteCounter to count the votes but instead of it being for the specific image it shows the same count on every image. How can i stop this and make it that each image has its own vote and how can i save it to the backend of parse?
heres my code so far:

```
class HomePage: UITableViewController {

var images = [UIImage]()
var titles = [String]()
var imageFile = [PFFile]()
var voteCounter = 0




   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    println(PFUser.currentUser())

    var query = PFQuery(className:"Post")

    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")

            for object in objects! {

                self.titles.append(object["Title"] as! String)

                self.imageFile.append(object["imageFile"] as! PFFile)

                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            println(error)
        }
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return titles.count


}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 500

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var myCell:cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell") as! cell

    myCell.rank.text = "21"
    myCell.votes.text = "\(voteCounter)"
    myCell.postDescription.text = titles[indexPath.row]

    imageFile[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data, error) -> Void in

        if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {

            myCell.postedImage.image = downloadedImage

        }
    }

    var swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
    myCell.postedImage.userInteractionEnabled = true;
    myCell.postedImage.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)


    var swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
    myCell.postedImage.userInteractionEnabled = true;
    myCell.postedImage.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

    return myCell

}


func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

        if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {

            switch swipeGesture.direction {
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right:
                voteCounter += 1
                println("Swiped right")
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left:
                voteCounter -= 1
                println("Swiped Left")
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use all the different arrays, just keep the array of `PFObjects` and use them directly. This object should also have the vote count as one of its columns so that when you download you get the count. So you also don't need your vote counter.

You should also look at using `PFImageView` To display the image. Either that or actually cache the downloaded images yourself.

To update the vote count you should use the [increment feature](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/increment-operators/) offered by `PFObject`.

Comment: how can i add it in to the PFObject? and for the image can you elaborate more?

Comment: The vote count? Add a number colum. It looks like you don't currently have anywhere to store the count. Get the votes sorted first and then consider making image handling more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you work with different pictures, for my part I prefer working with a single table for the tableView.
Every element of your table will correspond to a line of TableView like this :
NOTE : You will have to rearrange the code as you wish

```
class HomePage: UITableViewController {

    var dataTab : [FPObject] : []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Init your data array for tableView
        println(PFUser.currentUser())
        var query = PFQuery(className:"Post")
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
                for object in objects! {
                    self.dataTab.append(object)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                println(error)
            }
        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.dataTab.count
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 500
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        //Get Object at IndexPath.row in  dataArray for tableView
        let rowObject = self.dataTab[indexPath.row]

        let rank = rowObject["rank"]
        let votes = rowObject["votes"]
        let description = rowObject["Title"]

        myCell.rank.text = rank
        myCell.votes.text = votes
        myCell.postDescription.text = description


        //Asynchrone task
        rowObject["imageFile"].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data, error) -> Void in
            if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {
                //When download success -- reload tableview to update cells
                myCell.postedImage.image = downloadedImage
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }

        return myCell
    }

    //ACTION WHEN EDIT CELL TABLEVIEW -- Look differents screens
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {

        var upAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "UP") { (action, indexPath) -> Void in
            //Get object at index
            let updateObject = self.dataTab[indexPath.row]

            //Update data tableview // Increment vote
            self.dataTab[indexPath.row]["vote"] = updateObject["vote"] + 1

            //UPDATE data in Parse.com
            let objectId = updateObject["objectId"]
            var query = PFQuery(className:"Post")
            query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(objectId) {
                (postObject: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                    println(error)
                } else if let postObject = postObject {
                    postObject["vote"] = postObject["vote"] + 1
                    postObject.saveInBackground()
                }
            }

            //Reload tableview cells
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        upAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

        var downAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "DOWN") { (action, indexPath) -> Void in
            //Get object at index
            let updateObject = self.dataTab[indexPath.row]

            //Update data tableview // Increment vote
            self.dataTab[indexPath.row]["vote"] = updateObject["vote"] - 1

            //UPDATE data in Parse.com
            let objectId = updateObject["objectId"]
            var query = PFQuery(className:"Post")
            query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(objectId) {
                (postObject: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                    println(error)
                } else if let postObject = postObject {
                    postObject["vote"] = postObject["vote"] - 1
                    postObject.saveInBackground()
                }
            }

            //Reload tableview cells
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

        return [upAction, downAction,]
    }
}
```

screen result to upvote and downvote if you want to use this

[image]
I hope I have helped you

Ysée

Comment: Thank you very much for this but i think i want to keep the swipe to like and dislike feature. i will definitely be using some of this code and i really appreciate the help